# Как правильно парсить теги Html на Python

Tags: html, python

Есть вопрос как парсить Html страницы на python а точнее вот ссылка на страницу: https://3dtoday.ru/3d-models?page=1.
Именно надо парсить этот кусок кода:

```
<div class="threedmodels_models_list__elem__title">
                                <a href="https://3dtoday.ru/3d-models/for-home/kitchen/derzhatel-filtra-rozhka-kofevarki" title="">
                                    Держатель фильтра рожка кофеварки.
                                </a>
                            </div>
```

Не понимаю как спарсить текст тега `<a>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно было воспользоваться requests и bs4

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://3dtoday.ru/3d-models?page=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

element = soup.find_all('div', class_='threedmodels_models_list__elem__str')
elem_soup = BeautifulSoup(str(element[1]), 'html.parser')
title = elem_soup.find_all('a')[2].text

print(title)
```

Output:
Держатель фильтра рожка кофеварки.

Ответ на комментарий, чтобы получить заголовки 18 элементов, нужно добавить цикл

```
for index in range(18):
    elem_soup = BeautifulSoup(str(element[index]), 'html.parser')
    title = elem_soup.find_all('a')[2].text
    print(title)
```

Comment: Что нужно убрать что-бы парсить весь текст на странице с этим классом?

Comment: добавил в ответ

Answer (score 0):

Популярная библиотека для парсинга XML и HTML.
http://zetcode.com/python/beautifulsoup/

Разбор по похожему вопросу.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/13240700/13468321

Comment: Я пытался использовать Beautifulsoup но ничего не парситься

Comment: @kiber могу только посочувствовать. Пробуйте еще. https://devman.org/qna/8/ja-hochu-stjanut-informatsiju-s-sajta-kak-eto-sdelat/